# Remove list items separators/borders

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I've inspected the DOM but I still can't see where the separators/border are added to the items of a list. I would like to remove them.

[image]

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It lies in `div.x-list-item-label`, simply change its CSS style to:

```
border-top: none !important;
border-bottom: none !important; /* For the last row */
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, I definitely could have found it. But I'm wondering why it lies in a class called '...label'. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The method explained above is correct only if you want it to apply to EVERY single list in your app.

If you want to do it the proper way, you need to add an inline style to the list that you create. Here is how I did it in our application's inbox screen:

```
{
 xtype: 'list',
 disableSelection: true, // only if you want to disable selection of the list
 config: {
      style: {
           'border': '0',
      },
 },
 itemTpl: '<div>{itemContent}</div>'
}
```